# mariadb -select statement shows inaccurate time to query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm conducting a little test ... primarily for educational purposes... where I'm comparing a database in mysql with one in mariaDB. 
the data is almost the same.  the schema is identical but the mariaDB has a few records less than the mysql one.

I'm running the same query in both databases and i wanted to see how long each one took.  I'm used to seeing some stats like this at the end of my queries (sorry, I don't know what its officially called...)

```
16140 rows in set (8.80 sec)
```

This is what I get from mariaDB:

```
16020 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't know why the time is set to 0. 
I'm currently reading the manuals for mariadb but I'm not sure what to search for.  I'm google for "mariaDB query times" for now... but if anyone has some suggestions on what to search for or how to fix this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Likely solution:

Turn off the Query cache.  Or add `SQL_NO_CACHE` to the `SELECT`.

Possible explanation:

MariaDB may have an optimization that makes the query run much faster.  Let's see the query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Another possibility:

You had ENGINE=InnoDB in MySQL, but MyISAM in MariaDB, and you were doing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl;`.  MyISAM dead-reckons the number of rows; InnoDB has to count.